# Build Ant for Perforce integrated Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin, perforce

I have set up a Ant Build project in Eclipse. The project has been accessed via Perforce.

When I try to build the Ant project. I am able to see that compilation errors that shows that required JARs are not used for compilation. That's why its showing errors on some imports.

```
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 233 source files to F:\Aspire\depot\Compliance_IT\centralsurv\aspire\web\build\WEB-INF\classes
    [javac] F:\Aspire\depot\Compliance_IT\centralsurv\aspire\web\src\com\lehman\cad\gc\aspireGlobal\ADBUtils.java:4: error: package com.lehman.adbservices.datafeed does not exist
    [javac] import com.lehman.adbservices.datafeed.DataFeedProcessor;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] F:\Aspire\depot\Compliance_IT\centralsurv\aspire\web\src\com\lehman\cad\gc\aspireGlobal\ADBUtils.java:5: error: package com.lehman.adbservices.datafeed does not exist
    [javac] import com.lehman.adbservices.datafeed.Asset;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] F:\Aspire\depot\Compliance_IT\centralsurv\aspire\web\src\com\lehman\cad\gc\aspireGlobal\ADBUtils.java:6: error: package com.lehman.adbservices.datafeed does not exist
    [javac] import com.lehman.adbservices.datafeed.DataFeedProcessorFactory;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] F:\Aspire\depot\Compliance_IT\centralsurv\aspire\web\src\com\lehman\cad\gc\aspireGlobal\ADBUtils.java:7: error: package com.lehman.adbservices.datafeed does not exist
    [javac] import com.lehman.adbservices.datafeed.AssetRelationship;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] F:\Aspire\depot\Compliance_IT\centralsurv\aspire\web\src\com\lehman\cad\gc\aspireGlobal\AddUserServlet.java:19: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.*;
```

I want to build the working project successfully in Eclipse. There could be 2 choices to resolve this..
a. JavaClasspath is not pointing to JARs in build.xml  PFB the ant xml task and defitions.

```
<property name="source" value="${base}/src"/>
<property name="docroot" value="${base}/docroot" />
<property name="build" value="${base}/build"/>
<property name="config_src_dir" value="${base}/config"/>
<property name="lib_src_dir" value="${base}/lib"/>
<property name="webinf_dir" value="${build}/WEB-INF"/> 
<property name="classes_dir" value="${webinf_dir}/classes"/> 
...........
    <target name="compile" depends="copy">  
         <javac srcdir="${source}" destdir="${classes_dir}" compiler="modern" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" classpath="${java.class.path}" includeantruntime="false"/>    
         <copy file="${config_src_dir}/UserSessionService.wsdl" todir="${classes_dir}/com/lehman/esm/mwwapi/weblogic/client"/>
         <copy file="${config_src_dir}/UserSessionService.xml" todir="${classes_dir}/com/lehman/esm/mwwapi/weblogic/client"/>
    </target>
```

b. buildbath doesn't contain required JARs. I have updated the Buildpath preferences with required JARs. Though the Project explorer doesn't show LIB folder. Please find below screenshot.
[image]
Your solution/advice will be appreciated :)